# How do I get Excel to return a value based on the max value in a table?

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet-function

In the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NInP4.jpg) the largest value is 1.71, how do i return -2.25 and 235?

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your picture that you need a **two-dimensional** lookup.  Given a value within a table, retrieve both the column header and row header associated with that value.  Consider the following simple example:

[image]

We want the name and topic associated with the highest score.  The highest score in the example is *100*; so we want to retrieve *Jim* and *Spelling*

In **A7** enter:

```
=MAX(B2:F5)
```

This is our lookup value.  In **B8** we enter the **array formula**:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,1,MIN(IF($B$2:$F$5=A7,COLUMN($B$2:$F$5)-COLUMN($B$2)+1)))
```

In **B9** enter the **array formula**:

```
=INDEX($A2:$A$5,MIN(IF($B$2:$F$5=A7,ROW($B$2:$F$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)),1)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

The result:

[image]